# jQuery regex selector and get number from id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, regex

i have research form with few questions and answers and i'm trying to catch ID from id of form element (radio, checkbox, etc..). HTML form is generated dynamically from MySQL, that is a reason why id's and name's have only common value "question".

**I have inputs like this:**

```
<input type="text" name="question[1]" id="question-1" value="">
<input type="radio" name="question[2]" id="question-2" value="1"> Foo
<textarea name="question[3]" id="question-3"></textarea>
```

And i need to catch number from id. E.g. **catch number 3 from id="question-3"**. It is possible to do that?

There is my js code. When you change value of any form element with id started "question-", data will be post. It works, but i need detect number in ID element, because i would like to generate next one ajax request (GET) to remove answer (e.g. /research/delete-answer/?id=3).

```
$('[id^=question-]').change(function() {
    var formId = <?= $this->form->id; ?>;
    var dataString = $('[id^=question-]').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/research/save/?id=" + formId,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data, status) {
            console.log('Saved [' + status + ']');
            console.log('Data [' + dataString + ']');
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: `this.id.split('-').pop()`

Comment: Thanks, split('-') it works and it is best solution for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
id="[^-]+-(\d+)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/4

```
var re = /id="[^-]+-(\d+)/g;
var str = '<input type="text" name="question[1]" id="question-1" value="">\n<input type="radio" name="question[2]" id="question-2" value="1"> Foo\n<textarea name="question[3]" id="question-3"></textarea>';
var subst = '';

var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: Regexp? For this? OP, please don't bring an entire construction company to do the work of one man. `$(this).prop('id').split('-')[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^=question-]').change(function(event) {
    var id = $(event.target).attr('id').replace('question-', '');
```

should give you the number within the id of the element which triggered the change event if that is what you were looking for, I am not totally sure what you are asking.